# In Rules, how can I use a set the value of a taxonomy term reference field to multiple values?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

How can I set a taxonomy term reference field to two values using Rules?  The "Number of values" for the field is already set to two.

I set up a workflow in rules that works for setting a single value.  I tested this several times and encountered no problems.  However, when I changed the "Number of values" for the field from "1" to "2" and then edited the action to add two terms instead of just one, I got the following error message:

> - Warning: Missing argument 2 for taxonomy_options_list() in
>     taxonomy_options_list() (line 1375 of
>     /srv/bindings/e87a1e62cfd24fea9dd67cfd074d146c/code/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
> - Warning: Missing argument 3 for taxonomy_options_list() in
>     taxonomy_options_list() (line 1375 of
>     /srv/bindings/e87a1e62cfd24fea9dd67cfd074d146c/code/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).
> - Warning: Missing argument 4 for taxonomy_options_list() in
>     taxonomy_options_list() (line 1375 of
>     /srv/bindings/e87a1e62cfd24fea9dd67cfd074d146c/code/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.module).

When I attempt to set a value by triggering the rule, it fails and the rules debug log has the following output:

> - 3.235 ms Unable to get a data value. Error: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.
> - 4.254 ms Unable to evaluate action data_set.

What is the correct way to assign two terms at once to a single taxonomy term reference field?

Comment: Are you using the "Set a data value" action with a comma separated list of taxonomy term ids to set the value?

Comment: I am using the "Set a data value" action with "Direct input mode" to select two values from the select list of taxonomy terms.

Comment: Please, export your rule and show it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this is actually fairly easy to do in Rules.  By updating to the latest version of the Entity API (rc3-- I was stuck on rc1 due to a different bug that I resolved earlier today) with Rules 2.1, I was able to do this in the following way:

1. Choose the action "Set a data value".
2. Choose the taxonomy term reference field to set.
3. Control-click to select the taxonomy terms to add.

That's all there is to it, but there is one potential gotcha: these values didn't always save correctly for me.  This may be because I opened multiple tabs in Firefox and tried to save many different rules at once; for whatever reason, sometimes only one of the two values got saved.  I fixed this by simply checking all the values again manually and re-saving them until the values stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Patrick Kenny's step #3.

You may need to click the button "Switch to the direct input mode" button to reveal the terms available in your taxonomy field.[image]